# How to create a grid

Tags: c#, xna, grid, cell

I would like to create a grid, with cells(I believe this is the correct term for this, is it?)
Like this(take z,x,c,v,b as my "cells"):

```
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
  -----------------
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
  -----------------
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
  -----------------
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
  -----------------
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
  -----------------
  z|x|c|v|b|x|c|b|b
```

The order of the "cells" is random, so dont worry about that, also the lines are only there to help you visualize what i mean

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, I edited your question to remove fluff. Don't put tags in question titles please.

Comment: Well, to put it bluntly: How to create a grid in c# (not how to draw a grid)? @tnw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are [`Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

To make a grid specificly, you need a 2D array. For this example I will use a string as the data, but you can use any class you want.

```
string[,] cells = new string[width, height];
```

You can then access and set the values of these cells like so:

```
cells[x, y] = "z";
string something = cells[x, y];
```